# New record cascade failure on form

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, vba, ms-access-2016

If you don't have time for all this background, just looking at joins in the SQL inserted below would be greatly appreciated.

**Background**

I have a database I am using to track employee skill data (for current year and projected for next 5 years) at a company. 
I'm pretty aware that I set up the base tables in a not-so-good fashion, so I am fully expecting to get comment/suggestions about that. So if completely revamping my set-up and starting from scratch is my best option, I am open to that idea. Currently, though, below is my situation.

**Setup**

- All employees are rated in 15 different categories, and have projected values in how their skill values should change (grow) each year over the next 5 years in all categories.
- I made the base tables by skill category - so 15 base tables.
- I then made queries that compiled the skill data for all categories for all employees for a given year - so 6 queries total (current year, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022).
- I then made a form for edit-input of data. I used current year query as the base form, and included the other 5 queries as subforms.
- In the current year query, I included all the fields for basic *Employee* info as well from the one *Category* table I chose to include those in (I think of this is the 'Master' table, since it's the only one with these extra fields).
- All the other category tables only have *EmpName* and skill level value fields for each year. I've joined all 15 tables to this Master table using the *EmpName* field (which is the same for all tables).

**Problem**

I originally had an issue where I couldn't change any of the values in the form (so basically, it was read-only), but then I changed all the relationships to one-to-one, and that fixed that problem. 
However, I THEN had the bright idea of changing the *Name* field name to *EmpName* (since I read *Name* is not a good field name), and now when I try to save new data or edits, I get errors:

> Error: You cannot add/change ~ b/c related record is required & Update/CancelUpdate w/o AddNew/Edit)

I did go through all the SQL and VBA code and changed *Name* to *EmpName*, so all the tables/queries seem to be making to correct association. Also, this database is split into front end/back end. I have updated the links in front end since making all the above-noted changes. Also, I CAN add records directly into the table. So problem must be with relationships or code.

**Code**

The SQL for the query connected to the base form is below.

```
SELECT [Developement Scenario Formation].Department, [Developement Scenario Formation].Title,
       [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName, [Developement Scenario Formation].[2017], 
       [Product Design].[2017], [Technical Information Gathering].[2017], 
       [Developement and Design Commissions].[2017], 
       [Plant Support].[2017], [Quality Issues Management].[2017], 
       [Overall Product].[2017], [Product Knowledge].[2017], [Safety/Health/Env Knowledge].[2017], 
       [Equipment Maintenance].[2017], [Measuring Instruments].[2017], 
       [Report Making].[2017], [Reports and Information Acquisition].[2017], Language.[2017], 
       OA.[2017], [Developement Scenario Formation].Status, 
       [Developement Scenario Formation].[Inactive Date]
FROM [Report Making] INNER JOIN ([Quality Issues Management] 
INNER JOIN ([Overall Product] 
INNER JOIN (OA INNER JOIN (((((((((([Developement and Design Commissions] 
INNER JOIN [Developement Scenario Formation] 
   ON [Developement and Design Commissions].EmpName = [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Equipment Maintenance] 
   ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = [Equipment Maintenance].EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Language] ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = Language.EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Measuring Instruments] 
   ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = [Measuring Instruments].EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Plant Support] 
   ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = [Plant Support].EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Product Design] 
   ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = [Product Design].EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Product Knowledge] 
   ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = [Product Knowledge].EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Reports and Information Acquisition] 
   ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = [Reports and Information Acquisition].EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Safety/Health/Env Knowledge] 
   ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = [Safety/Health/Env Knowledge].EmpName) 
INNER JOIN [Technical Information Gathering] 
   ON [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName = [Technical Information Gathering].EmpName) 
   ON OA.EmpName = [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName)
   ON [Overall Product].EmpName = [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName) 
   ON [Quality Issues Management].EmpName = [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName) 
   ON [Report Making].EmpName = [Developement Scenario Formation].EmpName;
```

I have also included the VBA code for the form, since that may be what's causing the 'On Update' error.

```vb
Private Sub LEAVESUBFORMDUMMY_GotFocus()
    Me.[cntrlDevelopement Scenario Formation.2018].SetFocus
    Parent.SetFocus
    Parent.[SbFrm_2018 LEVELS (ALL)].SetFocus
    Parent.[SbFrm_2018 LEVELS (ALL)]![cntrlDevelopement Scenario Formation.2019].SetFocus
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activate()
    If Me.AllowAdditions Or Me.AllowEdits Or Me.AllowDeletions Then
         Me.Command57.Visible = True
     Else
         Me.Command57.Visible = False
     End If    
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
    If Status = acDeleteOK Then Call AuditChanges("Action", "DELETE", Form)
End Sub

Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
    If Me.NewRecord Then
        Call AuditChanges("Action", "NEW", Form)
    Else
        Call AuditChanges("Action", "EDIT", Form)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
    If Me.AllowEdits Then
         Me.Command73.Visible = True
         Me.Toggle96.Visible = True
     Else
         Me.Command73.Visible = False
         Me.Toggle96.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Me.Filter = "[Status] = 'Active'"
    Me.FilterOn = True
    Me.Requery
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Resize()
    If Me.AllowAdditions Or Me.AllowEdits Or Me.AllowDeletions Then
         Me.Label94.Visible = True
    Else
         Me.Label94.Visible = False
    End If    
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle96_AfterUpdate()
    If Me.Toggle96 = True Then
        Me.Filter = "[Status] = 'Inactive'"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    Else
        Me.Filter = "[Status] = 'Active'"
        Me.FilterOn = True
    End If        
End Sub

Private Sub Toggle96_Click()

    If Me.AllowEdits = True Then
        Me.AllowEdits = False
        Me.SbFrm_2018_LEVELS__ALL_.Locked = True
        Me.SbFrm2019_LEVELS__ALL_.Locked = True
        Me.SbFrm2020_LEVELS__ALL_.Locked = True
        Me.SbFrm2021_LEVELS__ALL_.Locked = True
        Me.SbFrm2022_LEVELS__ALL_.Locked = True
        Me.Command97.SetFocus
        Me.Command73.Visible = False
        Me.Command57.Visible = False
        Me.Label94.Visible = False
        Me.Toggle96.Visible = False
    Else
       Me.AllowEdits = True
       Me.Command73.Visible = True
       Me.Command57.Visible = True
       Me.Label94.Visible = True
       Me.Toggle96.Caption = "Show Inactive Profiles"
    End If

End Sub
```

I know, this is quite a mess. But basically, I just need to be able to add new records and update existing records. If you have any help to give, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: This is a database design problem. You should not be using 15 separate tables but **one** Skills/Category table with an indicator field of specific skill/category. Queries will be much easier to write and schema easier to maintain.

Comment: That is good to know. However, it does not answer as to why my code/set-up is not working. Can you tell me the specifics as to that? Why aren't new records going into the tables from my Query?